how to solve Warning: React does not recognize the popoverTarget prop
i was creating an language dropdown and i used new feature popover and thats the problem doesnt recognize it. please help guys
code languageDropdaownItem
interface IProps {
  handleClick: () => void;
  text: TLanguageText;
  className?: string;
  image: StaticImport | string;
}

const LanguageDropdownItem = ({
  handleClick,
  text,
  className,
  image,
}: IProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleClick}
      popoverTarget="language"
      className={cn(
        " flex justify-between overflow-hidden border-2 border-[#B0B0B0]  w-full bg-[#F6F6F6] py-[17.5px] px-[14px]",
        className
      )}
    >
      <p>{text}</p>
      <Image src={image} alt="" className="size-6 rounded-md" />
    </button>
  );
};

export default LanguageDropdownItem;


i didnt expect an problem, expect that it will work perfectly cause i did in clear component it was working
